# What do the responses "Jes" and "Ne" mean to the question "Ĉu ne vi volas pomon?"?

Tags: negation, questions

It is uncommon to receive a question with *ne* just before the subject. As far as I know, *ne* relates to the word just after it, so what would be the meaning of a simple *Jes* or *Ne* as responses to this question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply put, the answer depends on the expectations of the person you're talking to, so always strive to be clear and flexible.

A: Ĉu vi ne volas pomon?

B1: Ne, mi ne volas pomon.

B2: Jes, mi ne volas pomon.

Both answers are OK.

You run into the same issue with *dankon* - which to some people means *jes, dankon* and to others it means *ne, dankon*. Always say either *jes* or *ne*.

A: Ĉu vi volas pomon?

B1: Jes, dankon.

B2: Ne, dankon.

B3: Dankon.

B1 Accepted the offer. B2 declined the offer. B3 was not clear.

Comment: I'd appreciate it if you could place this answer under my recently asked question, http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/what-does-jes-and-ne-mean-when-responding-to-negative-questions

Answer (score 1):

Jen kion diras PMEG pri tiu demando: http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/demandoj_respondoj/respondvortoj.html#i-4zl :

> Kiam oni respondas pozitivajn demandojn, la uzo de la respondvortoj
>   jes kaj ne estas sufiĉe simpla. Sed oni uzas ankaŭ negativajn
>   demandojn, demandojn kun nea vorto. La uzo de jes kaj ne responde al
>   tiaj demandoj estas bedaŭrinde malpli klara. Ekzistas du manieroj uzi
>   respondvortojn ĉe negativaj demandoj. Unu sistemo estas pli ofta en
>   okcidentaj lingvoj, la alia sistemo estas pli ofta en orientaj
>   lingvoj. Tial oni povas paroli pri okcidenta kaj orienta uzado, sed
>   fakte en multaj landoj kaj lingvoj ambaŭ sistemoj ekzistas paralele.
>   Ankaŭ en Esperanto ambaŭ sistemoj estas hejmaj. Zamenhof pli ofte uzis
>   jes kaj ne laŭ la okcidenta sistemo, sed li ankaŭ plurfoje uzis la
>   orientan sistemon.

Kie la okcidenta sistemo esence respondas al la demando kvazaŭ ne enestus la vorto 'ne' kaj kie la orienta sistemo konfirmas ke tio ja ne estas tiel per 'jes', kaj neas tion, do pozitivigas la respondon, per 'ne'.

Kunteksto kaj kulturo tion klarigas kiam oni ne pli specife respondas.

En la kunteksto de ĉi tiu demando, oni demandas pri la persono kiu volas pomon, do se la respondo estas ke efektive vi ne volas pomon, eble alia ja volas.

Comment: I'd like to make a more general question only refering to negative questions, (for which this is a great answer too). Or would that be unnecessary?

Comment: Maybe we should edit/split the question...

Comment: Yeah, how does that work?

Comment: I've asked the question now. You are very welcome to answer it. http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1240/what-does-jes-and-ne-mean-when-responding-to-negative-questions