# What does "jes" and "ne" mean when responding to negative questions?

Tags: word-usage

Negative questions, in my experience, are fairly common in everyday speach. The questions themselves are easily understood, but not the responses.

> Ĉu vi ne faris viajn hejmtaskojn?
>
> Jes / Ne

If I finished my homework, should I use *jes* or *ne*? Logically *ne* should place a second negation to the phrase and therefore make it a positive statement. However, in my native native language (Swedish) I'd say *no* if I didn't to the homework. Maybe this is why I am confused.

Here are examples of similar questions:

> Ĉu vi neniam faris viajn hejmtaskojn?
>
> Ĉu vi faris neniujn el viaj hejmtaskoj?

Comment: This post relates to a question asked by Vanege, which is specifically about questions where *ne* comes before the subject. http://esperanto.stackexchange.com/questions/1171/what-do-the-responses-jes-and-ne-mean-to-the-question-%C4%88u-ne-vi-volas-pomon

Answer (score 4):

This is discussed in [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/gramatiko/demandoj_respondoj/respondvortoj.html) in section 22.4, under *Jes kaj ne ĉe neaj demandoj*.

There are two methods, the Western and Eastern. The Western system is the one you are used to; the Eastern system is the strictly logical one.

Both are used in Esperanto; therefore, it is a good idea to respond with care to negative questions. However, the Western system predominates, and was the one generally (but not in every case) used by Zamenhof.

Answer (score 3):

Posting this answer here at the request of the asker:

Simply put, the answer depends on the expectations of the person you're talking to, so always strive to be clear and flexible.

A: Ĉu vi faris neniom da hejmtaskoj?

B1: Ne, mi faris neniom da hejmtaskoj.

B2: Jes, mi faris neniom da hejmtaskoj.

Both answers are OK.

You run into the same issue with dankon - which to some people means jes, dankon and to others it means ne, dankon. Always say either jes or ne.

A: Ĉu vi volas pomon?

B1: Jes, dankon.

B2: Ne, dankon.

B3: Dankon.

B1 Accepted the offer. B2 declined the offer. B3 was not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Very nice answers so far, it just seems no one discussed the situation if I wanted to say I actually did the homework (German *doch* / French *si*), so here's for completeness. In such situation, I would use a full answer, technically speaking with either *jes* or *ne* or maybe even neither, but supported by a *ja*:

> Mi ja faris miajn hejmtaskojn.